# Only Show text on Child Post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show google ad on my wordpress attachment page which is child page to post on wordpress. I just want to show this ad only child post/page not on parent post. i want to show in the end of content so i tried this code

```
function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
  global $post;
if ($post->post_parent)  
    $aftercontent = 'Ad code here';
    $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after');
```

Above code show ad on both pages parent and child, I also tried this code in this way

```
function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
  global $post;
if ($post->post_parent)  {
     $aftercontent = 'code here';
    $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;
}
    return $fullcontent;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after');
```

If i use this code on parent page/post content not show . please help me, i hope i you understand what i want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
  global $post;
if(is_singular() && $post->post_parent > 0)  {
     $aftercontent = 'code here';
     $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;
     return $fullcontent;
}

else
    return $content;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after', 9999);
```

Comment: Thanks for help and your time, but its same error all parent page/post content not show.

Comment: try to increase the priority of your filter hook

Comment: can you please explain it so i can understand it.

Comment: official link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ 
for you add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after', 99999);

Comment: thanks again, i try this as you mention, but when i use {} in my code the content of parent post was not show. title of post and other things was show but post content not .   `function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
  global $post;
if ($post->post_parent)  {
     $aftercontent = 'code here';
    $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;
}
    return $fullcontent;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after');`  when used after if ($post->post_parent)   and close before return $fullcontent; . as you can see above in my question 2nd code , so i tried you codes but same error.

Comment: if i use your code with 1st code ( above in question) then it will show on parent post also.

Comment: when did i told you to use {}, i ask to assign priority to your hook

Comment: i dont said that you ask me to use {} , i said as this is already part of my code i got these error, so if i include your code line in my code still i got same error.  as you can see i have 2 version of my code and i got problem in both 1st code display also on parent post ( need only on child) and 2nd code will not show parent post content . so what is the problem in my code ?

Comment: what code you put inside $aftercontent = 'code here';

Comment: i will using adsense add code but at the time now i just tried this with ='code here' when it will work as i need i put ad code here.

Comment: are you sure you are checking or seeing a child page ( or post ) in your browser

Comment: its work for child page but when you open parent post content of parent post will not show  , so i need this work but also not make effect to parent post. - i need this for wordpress posts ( child post ) thanks .

Comment: oh, i just changed my answer , please try to use this new code

Comment: no , now its not display code here (ad code) in child post . but parent post is ok

Comment: but i thanks to you as you try to hard to help me . thanks again

Comment: thanks for help this one work with my code else
    return $content;
 }

Comment: here is working code `function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
  global $post;
if ($post->post_parent)  {
     $aftercontent = 'code here';
    $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;
    return $fullcontent;
 }
else
    return $content;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after');`

Comment: this is what i changed in my answer few minutes ago, i think you have not used that, but its fine, now we both have similar working answers

Comment: yes i see you answer , but modified this line with old code if(is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0)

Comment: just update your answer will make vote it up .. Good Night ,thanks  :)

Comment: `if(is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0)` this one not working, you sure?

Comment: @deva i changed my answer, now it will work for all post type (post, attachment, page, custom post types)

Comment: thanks again  @Tarun Mahashwari  i will mark answer. thanks for your time .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tarun Mahashwari  for help me to get working code.
Here is working code for posts and child posts.

```
function wpdev_before_after($content) { global $post; if ($post->post_parent) { $aftercontent = 'code here'; $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent; return $fullcontent; } else return $content; } add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after');
```

May be this code work for pages and child pages provided by @Tarun Mahashwari

```
 function wpdev_before_after($content) { 
      global $post;
    if(is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0)  {
         $aftercontent = 'code here';
         $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;
         return $fullcontent;
    }

else
    return $content;
 }
add_filter('the_content','wpdev_before_after', 9999);
```

Comment: Maybe you should accept the answer given by @Tarun Mahashwari instead of your own.

Comment: yes for sure but @Tarun Mahashwari  code maybe work for pages only , so i post my answer with both code , i ask to Tarun Mahashwari  for update answer and when answer updated i will mark ,so in future if any user need this this will help .